# How do I show a label on a many to many relationship in Directus?

Tags: php, many-to-many, directus

I have added working, many-to-many relationships to a directus api through the directus admin app, but in the directus app when going to add an item to a collection, the label for the select options are not being propagated. I am able to select items and save everything correctly, so I know the many to many relationship is set up correctly, but I cannot propagate the label correctly. I have tried several different methods, including using the . notation to access fields in the relating collection, but to no avail.

When using dot notation, the relationship never loads and only shows a loading sign, while when putting nothing in label works, but no label.

Below are a couple screenshots:

[This is where i put in the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJtWc.jpg)

[This is one of the many to many relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8eUB.jpg)

[This is the loading sign that never changes when using dot notation or anything in label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kame9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the name in directus 9. It's possible in the option Display Template.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you need to include the junction table (dot notation), just the field name in the related table, like this: `name`... and for the template, you need to use a template string, like this: `{{name}}`

Hope this helps! We're cleaning up the field creation process now to make this more intuitive.

Comment: That works! Wow, how simple. Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 1):

[image: dicectus api many to many]

This worked for me. Please dont confuse it with DropDown Template